# JAVA how to remove element from list 2 seconds after adding it?

Tags: java, processing

The lib I'm using is processing library. I'm currently making a game and I need to remove items from list every 2 seconds after adding it (item will be add by Keypressed SPACE). I've tried this:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

boolean timeStarted;

int timeDuration = 2000;
int startTime = 0;

if (timeStarted) {
            
    int currentDuration = millis() - startTime;

    if (currentDuration >= timeDuration) {

        items.remove(0);

        startTime = millis();
        timeStarted = false;
    }
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keycode == 32) { // SPACE
        startTime = millis();
        timeStarted = true;
        items.add("new item"); 
    }
```

But this only remove the first item in the list, and it will stuck if I press the SPACE too fast (add too many items at the same time).

Could anyone help me or give me some idea how to deal with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think a list and some variables to calculate the time when an element was saved is not the right choice to implement what you have in mind. I think you should look for some caching approachs. Im thinking about something like [Guava](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache) or [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)

Comment: @Eritrean Thanks for the comment, but I wanna finish this only by using the processing lib since I'm not familiar with others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally wouldn't mix and match threading and Processing together.

If you're using Processing, and are doing this for a game (thus probably dont require milisecond precision), why not just use the framerate as a time measurement? Your Processing programs are always supposed to run at a set `frameRate` (unless you have some performance issues). You also won't see anything happen untill the frame where the action happens has been drawn anyway, so it doesn't really matter if your action completed halfway between a frame, your end user won't see the difference.

The default `frameRate` in Processing is 30fps. You can set a custom rate using the `frameRate()` function ([docs](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html)). `frameCount` returns the number of frames drawn (0 on the first frame).

Thus, you can do something like the following pseudocode

```
int removeItemCheckpoint;
int removeItemDuration;

void setup()
{
    // 30 frames per second
    frameRate(30);
    // window is two seconds, so this duration will last two times the frameRate
    removeItemDuration = frameRate * 2;
}

void draw()
{
   if (some input)
   { 
      // set checkpoint to current frame count + the duration
      removeItemCheckpoint = frameCount + removeItemDuration;
   }

   // if current frame count is larger than the checkpoint, perform action
   if (frameCount > removeItemCheckpoint)
   {
      // set checkpoint to pseudo infinity
      removeItemCheckpoint = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      // remove item here
   }
}
```

If you want to handle this for multiple objects at a time, you could create something like a list of created list index/checkpoint [pairs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) and loop over those instead.

```
List<Pair<int, int>> toBeRemoved = new List<Pair<int, int>>();

// add a new pair
toBeRemoved.add(new Pair(itemIndex, frameCount + removeItemDuration));

// loop over the list

foreach (Pair<int, int> item in toBeRemoved)
{
    if (frameCount > item.getKey())
    {
        itemList.remove(item.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) My code failed to make a pair here (I'm using java 8)

Comment: **EDIT:** I've figured out a smiliar method to do this! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem.
The pair syntax may be wrong, it might need to say `new Pair<int,int>(itemIndex, frameCount + removeItemDuration)` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use while for checking element from list 2 seconds after adding.

```
// remove element from list 2 seconds after adding it
while (startedTime+timeDuration >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // If delete exit while
    items.remove(0);
    break;
}
```

and Use thread for removing your item when you can keypress space.

```
if (keycode == 32) { // SPACE
     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     items.add("new item"); 
     // Thread execute
     Thread thread = new Thread(new Remover(startTime, items));
     thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // remove element from list 2 seconds after adding it
    while (startedTime+timeDuration >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        // If delete exit while
        items.remove(0);
        break;
    }
     // whether item is deleted
    System.out.println(items);
}
```

Full code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        
        main.keyPressed(32);

    }
    
    // Integer instead of Keycode
    public void keyPressed(Integer keycode) {
        
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (keycode == 32) { // SPACE
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            items.add("new item"); 
            // Check items
            System.out.println(items);
            
            // Thread execute
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Remover(startTime, items));
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    
}

class Remover implements Runnable{
    
    List<String> items;
    
    int timeDuration = 2000;
    
    long startedTime;
    
    public Remover(long startedTime,List<String> items) {
        this.startedTime = startedTime;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // remove element from list 2 seconds after adding it
        while (startedTime+timeDuration >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            // If delete items,Exit while
            items.remove(0);
            break;
        }
         // whether item is deleted
        System.out.println(items);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to write these into one class (not separated), but I don't know where could I put the `Thread`...Also, I'm confused about `Thread`, what does it do?

Comment: @AAAAAAbc Threads can be used to perform complicated tasks in the background without interrupting the main program. Thread performs remove element of item when space key pressed in this situation in the background.  Reference https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_threads.asp